# What is the purpose of 'Version:' in PGP public key

Tags: key-management, pgp

PGP public keys look something like

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (GNU/Linux)

mQGiBEl2HAgRBAC9IZGQE3NRWFoXV7CcVRbo7xMe+nGPRMTOocA0pcv9N67R6CAZ
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I'm wondering why the 'Version:' line is always included and if it's safe to remove. Why advertize what version of GPG/PGP and operating system being used if decryption does not depend on information in the 'Version:' line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can safely remove that line. [RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-6.2) does not declare it as required.

> Currently defined Armor Header Keys are as follows:
>
> - "Version", which states the OpenPGP implementation and version
>   used to encode the message.
> - [...]

I also could not find any evidence of version data being included in the binary version, neither by reading the RFC nor by viewing at the package data using `gpg --list-packets`.

---

To remove it, use `--no-emit-version`. From `man gpg`:

```
   --emit-version
   --no-emit-version
          Force inclusion of the version string in ASCII armored output.   --no-emit-
          version disables this option.
```

Comment: Thanks. Searching "--no-emit-version" I was able to find [this](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gnupg/devel/46012), which shows an easy way to add --no-emit-version to enigmail.

Answer (score 2):

This version number will be usefull in the case in the future a known
version of OpenGPG will be announced broken on a given set of OS.

Upon receiving a signed or crypted message using this broken version
of OpenGPG, you will be able to decide to change your trust level attributed
to this key.

On the other hand, I don't see any real advantage to hide the origin
tracking information of a key generation.

Answer (score -2):

Displaying version data is a security vulnerability and should be disabled by default. This is a huge bug in PGP right now and it needs to be addressed by the core maintainers ASAP.

Comment: Why is it a vulnerability? Can you point to a bug report?